# How to get value from variable then copy to clipboard without using input?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy value of a variable to clipboard which is coming from ajax response. I have searched about it and find lot of threads, but issue is everyone asking to use `input` for value selection using JavaScript `select()` function. Following script I am trying which does not works,

```
success:function(data)
{
    var copyText = data.geturl;
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText);

    return false;
}
```

Can someone kindly guide me that is there any way to copy value of variable to clipboard without using `input`? I would like to appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: i would advise to only copy to clipboard using user input. since usually you don't want to overwrite the clipboard without the users permission. I am interested in the answer tho.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1139105) of all different ways to use the clipboard with JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: According to the [Moz Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility) `document.execCommand("copy")` is deprecated. I believe you should be using the [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) instead - although support here looks even worse. Looks like implementation varies, safer to go with user initiated?

Comment: Just adding, here's an extensive discussion that may answer your question: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

Answer (score -1):

After some research i think it is not possible to copy information to the clipboard without user input due to security restrictions imposed by browser vendors.

more information about this [here](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/270)

Answer (score -1):

I tried this One

[Copy to Cliboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709080/6616874)

But this will not work for me. I thought you might be able to find something from this